# AngularJS application coming up blank

Tags: html, angularjs

after I run the index.html file the web page seems to be blank & the console is empty as well with no errors. I'm new to this place and still learning. few tips would help me. Thanks.

I have also tried Lazyloading (typing the script tag at the end outside of ) Please help me out here.

index.html:

```
<head>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src = "file:///C:/Users/Arun/Desktop/js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak>
  <md-content class="md-padding">
    <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
      <p id="autocompleteDescription">
        Use <code>md-autocomplete</code> to search for matches from local or remote data sources.
      </p>
      <label id="favoriteStateLabel">Favorite State</label>
      <md-autocomplete
          ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled"
          md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
          md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
          md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
          md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
          md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
          md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
          md-item-text="item.display"
          md-min-length="0"
          placeholder="Ex. Alaska"
          input-aria-labelledby="favoriteStateLabel"
          input-aria-describedby="autocompleteDetailedDescription">
        <md-item-template>
          <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
        </md-item-template>
        <md-not-found>
          No states matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.
          <a ng-click="ctrl.newState(ctrl.searchText)">Create a new one!</a>
        </md-not-found>
      </md-autocomplete>
      <br/>
      <md-checkbox ng-model="ctrl.simulateQuery">Simulate query for results?</md-checkbox>
      <md-checkbox ng-model="ctrl.noCache">Disable caching of queries?</md-checkbox>
      <md-checkbox ng-model="ctrl.isDisabled">Disable the input?</md-checkbox>
      <p id="autocompleteDetailedDescription">
        By default, <code>md-autocomplete</code> will cache results when performing a query.
        After the initial call is performed, it will use the cached results to eliminate unnecessary
        server requests or lookup logic. This can be disabled above.
      </p>
    </form>
  </md-content>
</div>
</body>
```

js.js:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
      .module('autocompleteDemo', ['ngMaterial'])
      .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

  function DemoCtrl ($timeout, $q, $log) {
    var self = this;

    self.simulateQuery = false;
    self.isDisabled    = false;

    // list of `state` value/display objects
    self.states        = loadAll();
    self.querySearch   = querySearch;
    self.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;
    self.searchTextChange   = searchTextChange;

    self.newState = newState;

    function newState(state) {
      alert("Sorry! You'll need to create a Constitution for " + state + " first!");
    }

    // ******************************
    // Internal methods
    // ******************************

    /**
     * Search for states... use $timeout to simulate
     * remote dataservice call.
     */
    function querySearch (query) {
      var results = query ? self.states.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : self.states,
          deferred;
      if (self.simulateQuery) {
        deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function () { deferred.resolve(results); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
        return deferred.promise;
      } else {
        return results;
      }
    }

    function searchTextChange(text) {
      $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
    }

    function selectedItemChange(item) {
      $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
    }

    /**
     * Build `states` list of key/value pairs
     */
    function loadAll() {
      var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
              Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
              Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
              Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
              North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
              South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
              Wisconsin, Wyoming';

      return allStates.split(/, +/g).map(function (state) {
        return {
          value: state.toLowerCase(),
          display: state
        };
      });
    }

    /**
     * Create filter function for a query string
     */
    function createFilterFor(query) {
      var lowercaseQuery = query.toLowerCase();

      return function filterFn(state) {
        return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
      };

    }
  }
})();
```

expecting a autocomplete application

Comment: Do you miss `ng-app='autocompleteDemo'` or you set it on `<html>` tag ?

Comment: According to your example you missed the `ng-app` attribute to start as angular module, you can put it on `<html ng-app='autocompleteDemo'>` or `<body ng-app='autocompleteDemo'>`

Comment: Yes! I did miss that & few other angular src links. Now solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First add ng-app to your application
2. Then, you need to add angular-material, angular-animate and angular-aria dependencies to run this auto complete.

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.18/angular-material.min.css">
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.18/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="autocompleteDemo">
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak>
  <md-content class="md-padding">
    <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
      <p id="autocompleteDescription">
        Use <code>md-autocomplete</code> to search for matches from local or remote data sources.
      </p>
      <label id="favoriteStateLabel">Favorite State</label>
      <md-autocomplete
          ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled"
          md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
          md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
          md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
          md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
          md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
          md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
          md-item-text="item.display"
          md-min-length="0"
          placeholder="Ex. Alaska"
          input-aria-labelledby="favoriteStateLabel"
          input-aria-describedby="autocompleteDetailedDescription">
        <md-item-template>
          <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
        </md-item-template>
        <md-not-found>
          No states matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.
          <a ng-click="ctrl.newState(ctrl.searchText)">Create a new one!</a>
        </md-not-found>
      </md-autocomplete>
      <br/>
      <md-checkbox ng-model="ctrl.simulateQuery">Simulate query for results?</md-checkbox>
      <md-checkbox ng-model="ctrl.noCache">Disable caching of queries?</md-checkbox>
      <md-checkbox ng-model="ctrl.isDisabled">Disable the input?</md-checkbox>
      <p id="autocompleteDetailedDescription">
        By default, <code>md-autocomplete</code> will cache results when performing a query.
        After the initial call is performed, it will use the cached results to eliminate unnecessary
        server requests or lookup logic. This can be disabled above.
      </p>
    </form>
  </md-content>
  <script>
  (function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
      .module('autocompleteDemo', ['ngMaterial'])
      .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

  function DemoCtrl ($timeout, $q, $log) {
    var self = this;

    self.simulateQuery = false;
    self.isDisabled    = false;

    // list of `state` value/display objects
    self.states        = loadAll();
    self.querySearch   = querySearch;
    self.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;
    self.searchTextChange   = searchTextChange;

    self.newState = newState;

    function newState(state) {
      alert("Sorry! You'll need to create a Constitution for " + state + " first!");
    }

    // ******************************
    // Internal methods
    // ******************************

    /**
     * Search for states... use $timeout to simulate
     * remote dataservice call.
     */
    function querySearch (query) {
      var results = query ? self.states.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : self.states,
          deferred;
      if (self.simulateQuery) {
        deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function () { deferred.resolve(results); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
        return deferred.promise;
      } else {
        return results;
      }
    }

    function searchTextChange(text) {
      $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
    }

    function selectedItemChange(item) {
      $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
    }

    /**
     * Build `states` list of key/value pairs
     */
    function loadAll() {
      var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
              Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
              Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
              Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
              North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
              South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
              Wisconsin, Wyoming';

      return allStates.split(/, +/g).map(function (state) {
        return {
          value: state.toLowerCase(),
          display: state
        };
      });
    }

    /**
     * Create filter function for a query string
     */
    function createFilterFor(query) {
      var lowercaseQuery = query.toLowerCase();

      return function filterFn(state) {
        return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
      };

    }
  }
})();
  </script>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Been taking whole day for this problem. Could you explain how exactly did u debug this? I wasn't able to find it. Please try to explain the logic behind. Thanks